# cpu-z alternative for ubuntu

Tags: cpu, ubuntu-10.04, monitoring, specifications

I'm using ubuntu 10.04. Is there any application that has features like that of cpu-z?

Comment: are you looking for the "what is my cpu" features or other things?  (does CPU-Z do thermal sensor monitoring? i think it does but i'm mostly booted into Ubuntu these days...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`less /proc/cpuinfo` maybe? It's not that fancy, but still very useful. If you want to check temperature, voltage or such, look at `lm-sensors` package (`sensors` command in the console).

For latter case, there are also a lot of GUIs: ksensors, torsmo, applets for almost all desktop environments, gkrellm, conky. Two last are somewhat similar in purpose to sidebars in Microsoft' OSes, but are much more ascetic.

If you want to see which hardware is installed on the machine, there is a couple of commands which can do it. `lshw | less` will show you a more or less verbose information about your motherboard, BIOS and PCI devices -- the most useful part of the above is the motherboard one. `lspci` (or `lspci -v` if you want to see the details like IRQs or I/O ports) will show you list of PCI devices with their names, and `lsusb` (or `lsusb -v`, again, if you want the technical information about endpoints) will show you a list of USB devices. There are a couple of others, like `lspcmcia`, but it is unlikely you will need them.

`lspci`, `lsusb` and `lspcmcia` utilites are located in packages `pciutils`, `usbutils` and (surprise) `pcmciautils` accordingly.

To get the most verbose and precise information you should launch these utilites (especially in their *verbose* form, i.e. with one or more `-v` flags) with root privileges: using a root console or `sudo`. That's because some system info (PCI capabilites or USB endpoint status) is not accessible for non-root.

Comment: nope, I want to be able to determine the specs of the system. Like processor type, memory, etc,..

Comment: try lshw then... lshw -vvv to be more verbose

Comment: Extended answer. Hope that will help you.

Answer (score 1):

There's an open source project called [CPU-G](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cpug/) that tries to reproduce the look & feel of CPU-Z under Linux. I haven't tried it myself so can't say how well it works but definitely worth checking out.